Using an Exception Process to abort subs and functions that are running
Its quite amazing that vb.net does not provide a simple way to abort running subs/functions using a GUI button. I've filled a problem report with Microsoft but they still have not been able to resolve.
Original Question To Microsoft:
There seems to be a difference in how Exceptions are handled if running from Visual Studio (DEBUG or RELEASE) vs running it after a publish and application install.
My application requires the ability to abort an operation that calls multiple, sequential routines i.e. push button called runs test which calls sub 1 which calls sub2… etc. I have a global flag inside this button_click call that checks the running state first to see if it was already called before. If it was not, then it starts the process stated above. Note: the rest of the GUI is locked down except for this button to ensure other buttons are not pushed while this is running, only this same button.
If the user presses this button again (button enabled in sub 1), a global RUNNING flag is checked. If found to be true (running), the first thing done in the button code is to disable it and then Throw an “ABORT” exception.
If I put a breakpoint in this section of the button code and have DEBUG->WINDOWS->CALL STACK displayed, I can see this button press at the top of the call chain. When I then start single-stepping the code, it jumps back up to the last sub running before the button press. These subs do not have an exception handler so each aborts and keeps going back down the call chain until it gets back to Sub 1 which handles it and returns to the starting button code. This is what I expected and in the debugger, using the single step, it does exactly that.
If I run in RELEASE MODE (within visual studio), the same functionality occurs and it aborts with no un-handled exception errors. Granted, I cannot stop on the breakpoint but it must be following the same chain or it would create an ABORT exception (un-handled). Running it from a deployed installation (either with DEBUG or RELEASE compiled code) gives me an un-handled exception as soon as the button is pressed. See the attached picture.
Stack Image In Debug Environment
It seems like in the deployed code, the button becomes its own thread and therefore is put on the bottom of the call chain. By me throwing the exception, its considered to be un-handled since I do not have a TRY/CATCH for it. If I did, the throwing of this would be useless and I would never get an ABORT. See picture:
[Deployed Exception](https://i.sstatic.net/Fyk4R1tV.png)
Monitoring a global state flag was being done before but it was very slow reacting and requires constant checking to see if it got set. The exception approach works fast since application.doevent() are in various places along with each sub call to allow for the system to check for exceptions.
My questions are:

why are there differences between running code in the VS environment vs. from an installed copy
is there some setting that allows me to accomplish this exception process

Follow-up Questions To Microsoft And Example:
I’ve created a simple project that has a text box and one button (btnStartTest).
This example is to show how running it in DEBUG or RELEASE mode allows an ABORT exception to be thrown while running the program. I put a breakpoint inside the btnStartTest code to allow the STACK to be shown (Stack.png). Once the code is continued, it gracefully aborts and allows it to be run again.
Code is simulating:

allow init code to be run without the ability to abort
after running item 1, the main_test_caller() calls other routines (button allowed to create abort)
pressing abort button allows breakpoint to occur in btnStartTest, see Stack in VS environment.
continuing allows code to roll back down the stack to main_test_caller() which handles the ABORT exception and then returns to btnStartTest_Click
If I publish and install this same code, I get the second picuture (Publish.png) of an Unhandle exception. Why is there a difference in how the program runs?

EXPECTED RESULTS:
Installed ClickOnce application to run as it did in Visual Studio Environment.
Unfortunately, you cannot upload a zip file with the whole project. Below is the form code so the GUI will have to be re-created.
Imports System.Net.Security
Imports System.Timers
Public Class Form1

    Dim TEST_RUNNING As Boolean = False
    Dim ABORT_FLAG As Boolean = False
    Dim Status As New Commands()

    Enum Commands
        Yes
        No
        Wait
        Proceed
        Turn_ON
        Turn_OFF
        Stop_Move
        Force_Stop
        Forward
        Backward
        Read_Pulse_Count
        Stop_Pulse_Counter
        Clear_Pulse_Counters 'this command will reset both pulse counters, even if one or both are not enabled
        Check_Abort
        Run_Normal
    End Enum

#Region "Timer Declares"
    Private WithEvents delay_timer As New System.Windows.Forms.Timer
    Private Sub delay(ByVal milli_secs As Integer, Optional abort_check As Commands = Commands.Run_Normal)
        delay_timer.Tag = "run"
        delay_timer.Interval = milli_secs
        delay_timer.Start()

        While (delay_timer.Tag <> "stopped")
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
            If (abort_check = Commands.Check_Abort And ABORT_FLAG = True) Then
                delay_timer.Stop()
                Exit While
            End If
        End While
    End Sub
    Private Sub delay_timer_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles delay_timer.Tick
        delay_timer.Stop()
        delay_timer.Tag = "stopped"
    End Sub
#End Region


    Sub level_2()
        Dim i As UInt16

        Try
            btnStartTest.Enabled = True
            For i = 0 To 1
                txtBox_Msg.AppendText("Inside:level_2" + vbCrLf)
                delay(1000, Commands.Check_Abort)
            Next

        Catch ex As Exception When ex.Message <> "ABORT" 'this handles other exceptions
            MsgBox("Error Has Occurred" & vbCrLf &
                   "Routine: level_2" & vbCrLf &
                   "Aborting Program" & vbCrLf &
                   ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
            End
        End Try
    End Sub
    Sub level_1()
        Dim i As UInt16

        Try
            btnStartTest.Enabled = True
            For i = 0 To 1
                txtBox_Msg.AppendText("Inside:level_1" + vbCrLf)
                level_2()
                delay(1000, Commands.Check_Abort)
            Next

        Catch ex As Exception When ex.Message <> "ABORT" 'this handles other exceptions
            MsgBox("Error Has Occurred" & vbCrLf &
                   "Routine: level_1" & vbCrLf &
                   "Aborting Program" & vbCrLf &
                   ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
            End
        End Try
    End Sub
    Function main_test_caller() As Boolean
        Dim i As UInt16

        Try
            btnStartTest.Enabled = True
            For i = 0 To 2
                txtBox_Msg.AppendText("Inside:main_test_caller" + vbCrLf)
                level_1()
                delay(1000, Commands.Check_Abort)
            Next

        Catch ex As Exception When ex.Message = "ABORT"
            'handle abort
            main_test_caller = False
        Catch ex As Exception 'this handles other exceptions 
            MsgBox("Error Has Occurred" & vbCrLf &
                   "Routine: main_test_caller" & vbCrLf &
                   "Aborting Program" & vbCrLf &
                   ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
            End
        End Try
        main_test_caller = True
    End Function

    Sub init_tester()
        txtBox_Msg.AppendText("Inside:init_tester" + vbCrLf)
        delay(2000)
    End Sub
    Private Sub btnStartTest_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStartTest.Click
        Dim test_status As Boolean

        If TEST_RUNNING Then
            ABORT_FLAG = True
            btnStartTest.Enabled = False
            btnStartTest.Text = "...ABORTING..."
            btnStartTest.BackColor = Color.Yellow
            'update GUI
            Application.DoEvents()
            Throw New Exception("ABORT")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        btnStartTest.Enabled = False
        'Set Global Test Running Flag 
        TEST_RUNNING = True
        'Init Abort Flag To False
        ABORT_FLAG = False
        init_tester()

        btnStartTest.Text = "ABORT"
        test_status = main_test_caller()
        If ABORT_FLAG = True Then
            txtBox_Msg.AppendText("TEST ABORTED" & vbCrLf)
        ElseIf test_status = True Then
            txtBox_Msg.AppendText("TEST PASSED" & vbCrLf)
        Else
            txtBox_Msg.AppendText("TEST FAILED" & vbCrLf)
        End If
        TEST_RUNNING = False
        'Init Abort Flag To False
        ABORT_FLAG = False
        btnStartTest.BackColor = Control.DefaultBackColor
        btnStartTest.Enabled = True
        btnStartTest.Text = "START"
    End Sub
End Class

Is there another way to accomplish this task without constantly polling a cancel variable ?



I've filled a problem report with Microsoft but they still have not been able to resolve.: You may consider that .NET Framework has existed since the mid-2000s. Are you using a free copy of Visual Studio or did you purchase a Visual Studio Subscription? What is your level of expertise with VB.NET? (ie: how long have you been programming in VB.NET)?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5183623/17034

The article BackgroundWorker Class (you might need to select VB instead of C# using the dropdown towards the top-right) has an example that may work well for you. Or you could look into Task cancellation if that is more to your liking.

I'm using the Free version. I've been programming with VB since version 4.0. As to level of expertise, that is a broad question. I've written applications ranging from database I/O to test development environments. In addition, I use the VS environment with Visual Micro to program embedded developments with C++. I'm an engineer working for an EMS company.

The problem with a BackgroundWorker or other threading models is that they require a poll for cancellation. It can be called a Token or something else, but it still requires constant polling. I know what is running and I'm waiting for the task to complete OR be canceled. The doEvents() chain processes exceptions for Try/Catch and allows this to occur.

Using Application.DoEvents() is almost always an incorrect approach these days. You may consider following the recommendations given by @AndrewMorton. It's unclear what you mean by The problem with a BackgroundWorker or other threading models is that they require a poll for cancellation. It can be called a Token or something else, but it still requires constant polling. Are you stating that you consider using an if statement  a problem?

Unfortunately, you cannot upload a zip file with the whole project: While it may be discouraged by the owners of SO, some people choose to post the relevant code here (as you've done) and create a project on Github and share the URL here for anyone interested in viewing the entire project.

@MinnesotaKid What do you have against polling? It's the way to do it, by design.

When you’re dealing with external instrument communications and all the methods that entails, you can get pretty deep into the rabbit hole. One test routine can run 20-100 such measurement types which use underlying protocols i.e. RS232 etc. A full test program can have many such test routines.
What is nice about DoEvents, is it allows the messaging system to be serviced.  Why does this method work in the VS environment (debug & release) but not when its installed using clickonce ? Microsoft definitely has a bug. There should be a straightforward way to cancel subs/functions.

Microsoft definitely has a bug and has been notified. It’s under “consideration”…
I believe a workaround is to always call a routine like the below where processing time delays can occur. This ensures the exception stays on the same call chain where it can be processed properly.
    Sub check_for_abort()
        Application.DoEvents()
        If ABORT_FLAG = True Then
            Throw New Exception("ABORT")
        End If
    End Sub


If anyone comes up with a better solution, please chime in. Thanks for everyone’s input.

At this point, both VB.NET and C# are quite mature. In a previous comment, you stated, you can get pretty deep into the rabbit hole. Yes, that's how it is with program design. If it's not done correctly, things can get pretty out of hand. Sometimes, it's better to start over completely.

Have you considered using C#? You'll find far more resources available for C# than for VB.NET both on SO and elsewhere on the internet.

I'll need to check into C# down the line. I'm committed to C++ for using VS with Visual Micro for embedded development. For now, the solution I presented moved the peg forward. Thanks
